# Can Mr.Handy lvl up your vault dwellers

Tags: fallout-shelter

I was wondering, since Mr.Handy can collect loot can he also Lvl up your dwellers and  increase trained stats?

Answer (score 3):

No, he can't lvl-up your dwellers or increase stats. His purpose is only to collect resources (on one shelter floor, that he was assigned to) or caps (in wasteland).

Answer (score 0):

Just as Llja said, Mr. Handy cannot level up your dwellers or increase trained stats.

However, there are **Pets** that do exactly this:

[image]